# Getting Javascript Grails Jstree

Tags: grails, jstree

im trying to get jstree to work with

The first step I took was I added the following to the buildconfig.groovy

```
  plugins{
 compile "org.grails.plugins:js-tree:0.3.1"
}
```

Then I created my gsp and added the following to it to test it out which I got from the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53cvtbv9/1/)

```
       <html>
       <head>
    
     <g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>
    <jsTree:resources />

</head>
<body>



<div>
    <input class="search-input form-control">
</div>

<div id="jstree">

        </div>
  <script>


    

           $(function() {

            $(".search-input").keyup(function() {

              var searchString = $(this).val();
              console.log(searchString);
              $('#jstree').jstree('search', searchString);
           });


        $('#jstree').jstree({
            'core': {

                'data': [{
                    "id": "1.0",
                    "text": "Fresh Products",
                    "icon": "",
                    "state": {
                        "opened": false,
                        "disabled": false,
                        "selected": false
                    },
                    "children": [{
                        "id": "2.06.0",
                        "text": "Ethnic & Specialty",
                        "icon": "",
                        "state": {
                            "opened": false,
                            "disabled": false,
                            "selected": false
                        },
                        "children": false,
                        "liAttributes": null,
                        "aAttributes": null
                    }, {
                        "id": "2.07.0",
                        "text": "Natural & Organic",
                        "icon": "",
                        "state": {
                            "opened": false,
                            "disabled": false,
                            "selected": false
                        },
                        "children": false,
                        "liAttributes": null,
                        "aAttributes": null
                    }, {
                        "id": "2.08.0",
                        "text": "Prepared Foods",
                        "icon": "",
                        "state": {
                            "opened": false,
                            "disabled": false,
                            "selected": false
                        },
                        "children": false,
                        "liAttributes": null,
                        "aAttributes": null
                    }, {
                        "id": "2.09.0",
                        "text": "Seafood",
                        "icon": "",
                        "state": {
                            "opened": false,
                            "disabled": false,
                            "selected": false
                        },
                        "children": false,
                        "liAttributes": null,
                        "aAttributes": null
                    }, {
                        "id": "2.010.0",
                        "text": "Seafood",
                        "icon": "",
                        "state": {
                            "opened": false,
                            "disabled": false,
                            "selected": false
                        },
                        "children": false,
                        "liAttributes": null,
                        "aAttributes": null
                    }],
                    "liAttributes": null,
                    "aAttributes": null
                }, {
                    "id": "2.0",
                    "text": "Frozen Products",
                    "icon": "",
                    "state": {
                        "opened": false,
                        "disabled": false,
                        "selected": false
                    },
                    "children": [],
                    "liAttributes": null,
                    "aAttributes": null
                }, {
                    "id": "3.0",
                    "text": "Store Equipment ",
                    "icon": "",
                    "state": {
                        "opened": false,
                        "disabled": false,
                        "selected": false
                    },
                    "children": [],
                    "liAttributes": null,
                    "aAttributes": null
                }, {
                    "id": "4.0",
                    "text": "Packaged Grocery",
                    "icon": "",
                    "state": {
                        "opened": false,
                        "disabled": false,
                        "selected": false
                    },
                    "children": [],
                    "liAttributes": null,
                    "aAttributes": null
                }, {
                    "id": "5.0",
                    "text": "Retail Technology",
                    "icon": "",
                    "state": {
                        "opened": false,
                        "disabled": false,
                        "selected": false
                    },
                    "children": [],
                    "liAttributes": null,
                    "aAttributes": null
                }, {
                    "id": "6.0",
                    "text": "HBC/Non-Foods",
                    "icon": "",
                    "state": {
                        "opened": false,
                        "disabled": false,
                        "selected": false
                    },
                    "children": [],
                    "liAttributes": null,
                    "aAttributes": null
                }]



            },
            "search": {

                "case_insensitive": true,
                "show_only_matches" : true


            },

            "plugins": ["search"]


        });
    });


</script>




</body>
</html>
```

All that comes up when I run it is a blank search box and text saying "running"

Im not sure what is going wrong, it doesnt seem to be finding the js

Comment: "Since Grails 2.3, it is no longer possible to install plugins using the install-plugin command. Plugins must be declared in the grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy file." Did you declare it in the BuildConfig.groovy file like the error suggests?

Comment: Yes see above its the first thing I did @MikeC

Comment: Any idea why it isnt working? @MikeC

Comment: Yes. [It doesn't appear to be formatted correctly.](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.1/guide/conf.html#dependencyResolution). Beyond that, I've never worked with grails.

Comment: It is formatted correctly, the buildconfig file anyway whatever about the gsp. thanks anyway :)